# What is the distribution of $\log(t)$ if $t$ follows Gumbel distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose that the random variable $t$ follows the standard Gumbel distribution with the CDF $F_t(t)=e^{-e^{-t}}$, then what is the distribution of $\log(t)$? Is there any known distribution describe this?

To know the expectation value of $\log(t)$ is also very helpful!!

Comment: with the CDF of t, you can compute the CDF of log(t), for $F_t(x)=\mathbb{P}(t<x)=\mathbb{P}(log(t)<log(x))$.  Then, you can compute the density of log(t), and see if it matches any well known distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very helpful to describe the random variable and the variable of the CDF with the same variable t… so I call the Gumbel distributed variable X so we have $F_X(t)= e^{-e^{-t}}$ and you are asking for the distribution of $Y = \log(X)$ where I assume that $\log$ means the natural logarithm…

Then we have:  $$F_Y(t) = P(Y \le t) = P(\log(X) \le t) = P(X \le e^t) = F_X(e^t) = e^{-e^{-e^t}}$$

Calculating the density of Y gives us $$f_Y(t) = e^{-e^{-e^t}-e^t+t}$$

So expectation of Y is $$E[Y] = E[\log(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty tf_Y(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty te^{-e^{-e^t}-e^t+t}dt$$

Or using the equation: $$E[Y] = \int_0^\infty (1-F_Y(t) dt - \int_{-\infty}^0 F(t) dt$$

Have fun calculating it

Comment: But is there any simple way to calculate this integral? seems very difficult